# Как перехватить сообщение WM_NCCREATE?

Tags: c++, winapi

Как перехватить сообщение WM_NCCREATE (о создании окна) ?

Comment: Зарегистрировать класс `RegisterClass` с WndProc. (если свои)

Comment: Если чужие `SetWindowHookEx`

Comment: Можно пример? 
Я попробовал так:

HHOOK abc;
    abc = SetWindowsHookEx(WM_NCCREATE,NULL,NULL,NULL);

Ничего не вышло. Я скорее всего что-то упустил

Comment: Готового примера у меня нету, там не одна строка. Для WINAPI всегда есть MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, погуглите в сети много примеров.

Comment: WM_NCCREATE - буквально первое-второе сообщение, которое приходит в окно. Оно приходит еще до того, как вернется вызов CreateWindow[Ex]. Зачем оно Вам?